# iTextSharp get text from PDF - Input string was not correct format

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to do the simplest form of text extraction from a PDF using iTextSharp.

```
var reader = new PdfReader(file);
var text = string.Empty;

for (var page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
}
```

This throws the following exception:

`Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(ReadOnlySpan1 str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan1 s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)`

Digging deeper into the callstack I see that the number that is about to be parsed is `-115` and it seems like it should be a positive number.
So possibly something weird with this specific PDF.
(It seems it is inside CreateFont, and negative font sizes makes little sense. not sure if this is the actual issue though)

The problem is that we are not in control of those PDF's they are sent to us from customers.

is there any way around this? or is the issue something else?

I'm not sure what more to post here, let me know if there is something else I can provide.

Comment: It sounds like this issue is very specific to your environment, so about the only thing you can do is grab the iTextSharp source and modify it to your needs.

Comment: I was hoping there was some form of settings to ignore various types of parse errors. I'm really just interested in getting the raw text, ignoring fonts etc.

Comment: If you shared the pdf, we might be able to help more.